# Count before filter in django

Tags: django

I have a ModelViewSet with their own filter.

```
class XList(viewsets.ModelViewSet,):

    serializer_class = serializers.XXX
    queryset = models.XXX.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'field_id'
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = filters.MYOWNFILTER
```

I want show in response the count of data before and after filtering.

My desired answer would be,

```
{
  "next": 2,
  "previous": null,
  "count": 20,
  "TOTAL_COUNT": 100
  "size": 10,
  "results": [
    {} ] }
```

where TOTAL_COUNT would be the total count of data before any filter, and count, the count of data after filter.

Now, I've got the following response. I need the total count.

```
{
  "next": 2,
  "previous": null,
  "count": 20,
  "size": 10,
  "results": [
    {} ] }
```

I'm using pagination to get the response.

```
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'next': self.page.next_page_number() if self.page.has_next() else None,
            'previous': self.page.previous_page_number() if self.page.has_previous() else None,
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'size': len(data),
            'results': data
```

Comment: What does "TOTAL_COUNT" represent in your response?

Comment: It would be like a count in queryset = models.XXX.objects.all(). But my reponse is only getting me the count in the filtered queryset.